# How to securely lock down a MongoDB database?

Tags: mongodb, security

In the beginning of the year, [lots of MongoDB databases were hacked](https://snyk.io/blog/mongodb-hack-and-secure-defaults/). This also included my database. Yesterday I noticed my brand new database with authorization enabled was hacked as well. The username and password is very secure (16+ characters password with random characters and symbols).

I've now decided to fully secure it, but I honestly don't know where to proceed. I already have:

```
security:
    authorization: enabled
```

and that should be enough (after `sudo service mongod restart`). I only have 1 database and no admin user, but anonymous access from a remote connection is still allowed. I keep reading many places, that I should run mongod like `mongod --auth`, but that it's the same as enabling authorization as I've done above.

At this point I'm struggling to disable anonymous authentication on the server. What did I miss? Why can I authenticate without an account?

Comment: The `security.authorization` configuration directive is equivalent to the command line `--auth` option. Can you check that security is enabled via the `mongo` shell: the output of `db.serverCmdLineOpts().parsed.security.authorization`  should be `enabled`. What specific version of MongoDB are you using? How did you create the initial user? If you have properly enabled authentication by [creating an initial user](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/#create-the-user-administrator) (which normally should have the user admin role), anon access should no longer be allowed

Comment: @Stennie Running the command will just say `authorization is undefined`. `--auth` is not enabled and the `mongod.conf` file does not load correctly, I guess. I did create a new admin user (`use admin`, `db.createUser()`) just now, restarted using `sudo service mongod restart`, but I can still log in anonymously.

Comment: What O/S and version of MongoDB server are you using? If `authorization is undefined`, it definitely sounds like the expected configuration file isn't being used. Running `db.serverCmdLineOpts().parsed` in the `mongo` shell will return all of the command line options including the config file path (`db.serverCmdLineOpts().parsed.config`).

Comment: @Stennie I'm using MongoDB version 3.4.7 and it's on a Debian server. `db.serverCmdLineOpts().parsed` returns an empty object.

Answer (score 0):

To enable security you'll want to follow the [Security Checklist](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/?_ga=1.226901277.1012290092.1437423941) on the MongoDB Website.

[Here you are provided with role based authorization and authentication instructions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authorization/).  It's also advised you disable listening to all ethernet interfaces and bind your MongoDB ports to the interfaces you'd like exposed.

[For a guide to network hardening, you will want to review these instructions,](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-network/) but the most important aspect is to avoid unwanted network exposure. Consider using a firewall or security groups (if in cloud).

Comment: It looks like `mongod.conf` is not enabling the authorization flag. How do I make sure `sudo service mongod start` actually uses the mongod.conf file?

Comment: This is specific to your OS distro.  I recommend reading the config for your OS and where the startup info would be located. IE: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/